# vba converting multiple pdf in folder to text file

Tags: vba, pdf, text-files

I was trying to run a vba to convert multiple pdf file in a folder into txt file in another folder. however, I encountered the following error which I was not able to resolve.

The error is at Set jsObj = AcroXPDDoc.GetJSObject which gave me a runtime error 91: "Object variable or With block variable not set"

Can anyone help?
Thanks.

:Updated with new code

```
Option Explicit

Sub convertpdf5()

 Dim AcroXApp As Acrobat.acroApp
 Dim AcroXAVDoc As Acrobat.AcroAVDoc
 Dim AcroXPDDoc As Acrobat.AcroPDDoc
 Dim Filename As Variant
 Dim jsObj As Object
 Dim sfolder As String
 Dim dfolder As String
 Dim spath As String
 Dim dpath As String
 Dim SFilename As Variant
 Dim DFilename As Variant
 Dim objFolder As folder
 Dim objFile As file
 Dim NextRow As Long

sfolder = "C:\users\chanhc\desktop\test folder\"
spath = sfolder & "*.pdf"
SFilename = Dir(spath)

dfolder = "C:\users\chanhc\desktop\test folder after\"
dpath = dfolder & "*.txt"
DFilename = Dir(dpath)

'Creating a FileSystemObject
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
'Specify the path of the folder
'Create the object of this folder
Set objFolder = fso.GetFolder(sfolder)
'Check if the folder is empty or not
If objFolder.Files.count = 0 Then
  MsgBox "No files were found...", vbExclamation
  Exit Sub

End If

NextRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files

Cells(NextRow, 1).Value = sfolder & objFile.Name

NextRow = NextRow + 1

Next objFile

For Each Filename In Sheet1.Range("a2:a4")

 Set AcroXApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
 'AcroXApp.Show
 Set AcroXAVDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")
 AcroXAVDoc.Open Filename, "Acrobat"
 Set AcroXPDDoc = AcroXAVDoc.GetPDDoc
 Set jsObj = AcroXPDDoc.GetJSObject
 jsObj.SaveAs DFilename, "com.adobe.acrobat.plain-text"


 AcroXAVDoc.Close False
 AcroXApp.Hide
 AcroXApp.Exit

Next Filename

End Sub
```

Comment: **First put `Option Explicit` at the top of your module** and then compile (F9) to make sure everything's properly declared.

Comment: Also, is Reader opening visibly? Are you sure it's opening the correct file?  Confirm by putting a line `MsgBox fileName`  just before the line that's causing the error

Comment: I have inserted and the new code as below but it still show the same message.

Comment: What does the `MsgBox` say when it pops up before the error occurs?  (I'm trying to confirm that you're filename is correct in the variable.)

Comment: the msgbox works when i removed my files in the folder. so for the first part of the coding it works fine..

Comment: what do you mean `the msgbox works`?  What does it display?  And what do you mean `when i removed my files in the folder`?  What files? Which folder?

Comment: for pdf files in .sfolder. Msgbox "no files were found" was displaying fine.

Comment: What?  I suggested (above) that you add a new line: `MsgBox fileName` **just before** the line that the error occurs on (`Set jsObj = AcroXPDDoc.GetJSObject`).  The Msgbox should pop up the name of a file.  **If there is no filename displayed then there is no PDF file to open, which is why you are getting the error.**  (You can't **convert "no file" to text**!)

Comment: ok i did what u said and the `msgbox` shows..

Comment: Does it show a filename?? or is it blank??

Comment: It's blank, right?  You said you're trying to ***`convert multiple pdf file in a folder `***  but *it can't find a filename*

Comment: my bad.. its showing blank. so i need to resolved this.

Comment: i have files in the folder..

Comment: in which folder??\

Comment: inside .sfolder which are all pdf files..

Comment: are the files listed in Column A of the worksheet right now?

Comment: Yes there are.. ok I have change `AcroXAVDoc.Open Filename, "Acrobat"` to `AcroXAVDoc.Open sFilename, "Acrobat"` and it shows the first file on column A..

Comment: I'll start an answer below

Answer (score 1):

I think I'm starting to understand your problem and it has nothing to do with Adobe.  Your code to list the files is not working properly.

For one thing, you're combining 2 different methods of listing files.  (`Dir` and `FileSystemObject`s are not used together.

Also why are you listing the files on the sheet and then getting the name from the sheet?

I mistakenly assumed that you had followed the [steps in the FAQ about postings example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  A **Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**.

---

When you're having a problem with a section if your code, you need to **Start Over From Scratch**

> Create a new program, adding in only what is needed to see the problem. This can be faster for vast systems where you *think* you already know the source of the problem.

So, first see if your code to convert the PDF works BY ITSELF:

```
Sub ONLYConvertPDF()

    Dim AcroXApp As Acrobat.acroApp
    Dim AcroXAVDoc As Acrobat.AcroAVDoc
    Dim AcroXPDDoc As Acrobat.AcroPDDoc

    Dim Filename As String, DFilename As String, jsObj As Object

    Filename = "C:\users\chanhc\desktop\test folder\__ENTER_FILENAME__.PDF"  '<<ENTER A FILEMNAME HERE
    DFilename = "C:\users\chanhc\desktop\test folder after\TEST_OUTPUT_FILE.TXT"
    Set AcroXApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
    AcroXApp.Show  
    Set AcroXAVDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")
    AcroXAVDoc.Open Filename, "Acrobat"
    Set AcroXPDDoc = AcroXAVDoc.GetPDDoc
    Set jsObj = AcroXPDDoc.GetJSObject
    jsObj.SaveAs DFilename, "com.adobe.acrobat.plain-text"

    AcroXAVDoc.Close False
    AcroXApp.Hide
    AcroXApp.Exit

End Sub
```

Replace the string to give `FileName` the name of one existing file.  Run the code.  Does it work?  Did it convert the file?

> Besides taking out all code that wasn't for converting the PDF, I also uncommented `AcroXApp.Show`...  You should **never** hide something you're troubleshooting!  Also, I'm not sure why you were using `Variant` for `String`s but I changed those too.

---

**Once the above works fine by itself** then we work on troubleshooting the next step: looping through the files one at a time.

Instead of trying to explain what what wrong with that section of your code, I wrote you a simpler procedure to loop through the source folder, return all the filenames along with what the destination filename will be.

**It doesn't convert anything, it just pretends to for now.**

```
Option Explicit

Sub TEST_ListFiles()

    Const sPath = "C:\users\chanhc\desktop\test folder\"
    Const sExt = ".pdf"
    Const dPath = "C:\users\chanhc\desktop\test folder after\"
    Const dExt = ".txt"

    Dim sName As String, dName As String, fCount As Long

    'loop through all files in source
    sName = Dir(sPath & "*" & sExt)

    Do While sName <> ""
        fCount = fCount + 1

        'we have sName. Now figure out dName
        dName = Left(sName, InStrRev(sName, ".") - 1) & dExt

        'This will be the spot where you convert the PDF's to text, but NOT UNTIL
        'this code lists all the files properly, we can add it the other code to
        'actually convert the PDF's (which we know is working since we tested is BY ITSELF.)

        'For TESTING we will ONLY show the name is a msgbox:
        MsgBox "Converting PDF File #" & fCount & ": " & vbLf & _
                sPath & sName & " -> " & dPath & dName


        'find the next file
        sName = Dir
    Loop

    MsgBox "Found " & fCount & " files."
End Sub
```

Once that section functions properly by itself, you can add the two pieces of code together.

---

Once the above procedure is properly listing the source and destination, we can ***think*** about putting them together.

I *think*, that actually, in order to keep these nice, neat procedures separate, let's change the first one like this:

It will be stand-alone, and take the parameters for sFile & dFile, and we can call it each time we want to convert a file.

```
Sub ConvertOnePDF(sFile As String, dFile As String)

    Dim AcroXApp As Acrobat.acroApp, AcroXAVDoc As Acrobat.AcroAVDoc
    Dim AcroXPDDoc As Acrobat.AcroPDDoc, jsObj As Object

    Set AcroXApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
    'AcroXApp.Show
    Set AcroXAVDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")
    AcroXAVDoc.Open sFile, "Acrobat"
    Set AcroXPDDoc = AcroXAVDoc.GetPDDoc
    Set jsObj = AcroXPDDoc.GetJSObject
    jsObj.SaveAs dFile, "com.adobe.acrobat.plain-text"

    AcroXAVDoc.Close False
    AcroXApp.Hide
    AcroXApp.Exit

End Sub
```

---

Once you have the two procedures working , you can add this under the MsgBox in `Test_Listfiles`:

```
ConvertOnePDF sName, dName
```

and that should be it!

Comment: ashleedawg, appreciate your time explaining it in detail.. I have tried the part on converting the pdf to text and it works.. so how do I troubleshoot from here?

Comment: see my answer.  now you trying listing the files (WITHOUT converting the PDF)

Comment: Greatly appreciate it! the 2 codes work great and i manage to list the file in another column! but how to I merge them to work? didn't manage to do it..