# Opening Several PDF Files through Excel VBA and Saving as Text files

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I am trying to open several pdf files in a folder and save them as .txt files.

I have tried the approaches in the following thread

[vba converting multiple pdf in folder to text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49396929/vba-converting-multiple-pdf-in-folder-to-text-file)

As suggested in the answer to the above thread, I tried the following code which failed with an error "User-defined type not defined"

```
Sub ONLYConvertPDF()

    Dim AcroXApp As Acrobat.AcroApp
    Dim AcroXAVDoc As Acrobat.AcroAVDoc
    Dim AcroXPDDoc As Acrobat.AcroPDDoc

    Dim Filename As String, DFilename As String, jsObj As Object

    Filename = "C:\MyPath\MyFile.pdf"
    DFilename = "C:\MyPath\MyFile.txt"
    Set AcroXApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
    AcroXApp.Show
    Set AcroXAVDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")
    AcroXAVDoc.Open Filename, "Acrobat"
    Set AcroXPDDoc = AcroXAVDoc.GetPDDoc
    Set jsObj = AcroXPDDoc.GetJSObject
    jsObj.SaveAs DFilename, "com.adobe.acrobat.plain-text"

    AcroXAVDoc.Close False
    AcroXApp.Hide
    AcroXApp.Exit

End Sub
```

I have tried similar other threads involving Acrobat.acroApp, Acrobat.AcroAVDoc, Acrobat.AcroPDDoc but somewhere the same error repeats.

I also tried the Follow Hyperlink method to open pdf documents suggested in one of the threads on this forum but that method does not seem to work if you want to close the file after the file is manipulated. (I do not know how to close the file)

I have added the following libraries

[image]

When i tried to add a) PDFPrevHndlr 1.0 Type Library & b) PDFShellServer 1.0 Type Library (I do not know if either of them is necessary) I got an error "Error in loading DLL"

Do I need to add anything? I have Adobe Acrobat Reader DC installed

[image]

I do not have a good understanding of handling libraries, dLLs etc. 
Can someone help please? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Could you show us your code and tell us what line has the error?

Comment: added the code.

Comment: It looks like you need to install Acrobat Pro to have the dll's you need. See this https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2062763.

Answer (score 0):

[Xpdf](https://www.xpdfreader.com/download.html) provides some command-line tools, one is pdftotext.exe, what exports text from pdf to a file.

```vb
Private Sub PdfToText(ByVal PdfPath As String, ByVal TextPath As String)
Const PathToPdfToText As String = "" '"path\to\exe" 'add path to exe if not in windows path
With CreateObject("wscript.shell")
    .Run Chr(34) & PathToPdfToText & "pdftotext.exe" & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & PdfPath & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & TextPath & Chr(34), 1, 1
End With
End Sub
```

use like

```vb
PdfToText "path\to\pdfdoc.pdf", "path\to\textfile.txt"
```

Old reader control suggestion (maybe useful for someone) is missing SaveAs method

Get Adobe Reader AciveX control in Office x86

On an elevated powershell do:

```
& "$env:SystemRoot\SysWOW64\regsvr32"  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\Acrobat\ActiveX\AcroPDFImpl.dll"
```

to register the control.

After registering you have an "Adobe PDF Reader Imp" ActiveX control that can be used on x86. Credits for that go to [Nouba](http://office-loesung.de/p/viewtopic.php?f=167&t=755656&p=3114270&hilit=adobe+reader#p3114279).

But I am not sure if Reader provides saveas text.

Answer (score 0):

You need Adobe Acrobat Professional installed!  Try this code.

```
Option Explicit
Option Private Module

Sub SavePDFAsOtherFormat(PDFPath As String, FileExtension As String)

    'Saves a PDF file as another format using Adobe Professional.

    'By Christos Samaras
    'https://myengineeringworld.net/////

    'In order to use the macro you must enable the Acrobat library from VBA editor:
    'Go to Tools -> References -> Adobe Acrobat xx.0 Type Library, where xx depends
    'on your Acrobat Professional version (i.e. 9.0 or 10.0) you have installed to your PC.

    'Alternatively you can find it Tools -> References -> Browse and check for the path
    'C:Program FilesAdobeAcrobat xx.0Acrobatacrobat.tlb
    'where xx is your Acrobat version (i.e. 9.0 or 10.0 etc.).

    Dim objAcroApp      As Acrobat.AcroApp
    Dim objAcroAVDoc    As Acrobat.AcroAVDoc
    Dim objAcroPDDoc    As Acrobat.AcroPDDoc
    Dim objJSO          As Object
    Dim boResult        As Boolean
    Dim ExportFormat    As String
    Dim NewFilePath     As String

    'Check if the file exists.
    If Dir(PDFPath) = "" Then
        MsgBox "Cannot find the PDF file!" & vbCrLf & "Check the PDF path and retry.", _
                vbCritical, "File Path Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Check if the input file is a PDF file.
    If LCase(Right(PDFPath, 3)) <> "pdf" Then
        MsgBox "The input file is not a PDF file!", vbCritical, "File Type Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Initialize Acrobat by creating App object.
    Set objAcroApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")

    'Set AVDoc object.
    Set objAcroAVDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")

    'Open the PDF file.
    boResult = objAcroAVDoc.Open(PDFPath, "")

    'Set the PDDoc object.
    Set objAcroPDDoc = objAcroAVDoc.GetPDDoc

    'Set the JS Object - Java Script Object.
    Set objJSO = objAcroPDDoc.GetJSObject

    'Check the type of conversion.
    Select Case LCase(FileExtension)
        Case "eps": ExportFormat = "com.adobe.acrobat.eps"
        Case "html", "htm": ExportFormat = "com.adobe.acrobat.html"
        Case "jpeg", "jpg", "jpe": ExportFormat = "com.adobe.acrobat.jpeg"
        Case "jpf", "jpx", "jp2", "j2k", "j2c", "jpc": ExportFormat = "com.adobe.acrobat.jp2k"
        Case "docx": ExportFormat = "com.adobe.acrobat.docx"
        Case "doc": ExportFormat = "com.adobe.acrobat.doc"
        Case "png": ExportFormat = "com.adobe.acrobat.png"
        Case "ps": ExportFormat = "com.adobe.acrobat.ps"
        Case "rft": ExportFormat = "com.adobe.acrobat.rft"
        Case "xlsx": ExportFormat = "com.adobe.acrobat.xlsx"
        Case "xls": ExportFormat = "com.adobe.acrobat.spreadsheet"
        Case "txt": ExportFormat = "com.adobe.acrobat.accesstext"
        Case "tiff", "tif": ExportFormat = "com.adobe.acrobat.tiff"
        Case "xml": ExportFormat = "com.adobe.acrobat.xml-1-00"
        Case Else: ExportFormat = "Wrong Input"
    End Select

    'Check if the format is correct and there are no errors.
    If ExportFormat <> "Wrong Input" And Err.Number = 0 Then

        'Format is correct and no errors.

        'Set the path of the new file. Note that Adobe instead of xls uses xml files.
        'That's why here the xls extension changes to xml.
        If LCase(FileExtension) <> "xls" Then
            NewFilePath = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(PDFPath, ".pdf", "." & LCase(FileExtension))
        Else
            NewFilePath = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(PDFPath, ".pdf", ".xml")
        End If

        'Save PDF file to the new format.
        boResult = objJSO.SaveAs(NewFilePath, ExportFormat)

        'Close the PDF file without saving the changes.
        boResult = objAcroAVDoc.Close(True)

        'Close the Acrobat application.
        boResult = objAcroApp.Exit

        'Inform the user that conversion was successfully.
        MsgBox "The PDf file:" & vbNewLine & PDFPath & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        "Was saved as: " & vbNewLine & NewFilePath, vbInformation, "Conversion finished successfully"

    Else

        'Something went wrong, so close the PDF file and the application.

        'Close the PDF file without saving the changes.
        boResult = objAcroAVDoc.Close(True)

        'Close the Acrobat application.
        boResult = objAcroApp.Exit

        'Inform the user that something went wrong.
        MsgBox "Something went wrong!" & vbNewLine & "The conversion of the following PDF file FAILED:" & _
        vbNewLine & PDFPath, vbInformation, "Conversion failed"

    End If

    'Release the objects.
    Set objAcroPDDoc = Nothing
    Set objAcroAVDoc = Nothing
    Set objAcroApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

See the link below for more details.

https://myengineeringworld.net/2013/03/vba-macro-to-convert-pdf-files-into.html

Or, if you don't have a Acrobat installed, try the solution below, and of course, change the code to suit your needs.

```
Sub ChangeDocsToTxtOrRTFOrHTML()
    'with export to PDF in Word 2007
    Dim fs As Object
    Dim oFolder As Object
    Dim tFolder As Object
    Dim oFile As Object
    Dim strDocName As String
    Dim intPos As Integer
    Dim locFolder As String
    Dim fileType As String
    On Error Resume Next

    locFolder = InputBox("Enter the folder path to DOCs", "File Conversion", "C:\Users\your_path_here\")
    Select Case Application.Version
        Case Is < 12
            Do
                fileType = UCase(InputBox("Change DOC to TXT, RTF, HTML", "File Conversion", "TXT"))
            Loop Until (fileType = "TXT" Or fileType = "RTF" Or fileType = "HTML")
        Case Is >= 12
            Do
                fileType = UCase(InputBox("Change DOC to TXT, RTF, HTML or PDF(2007+ only)", "File Conversion", "TXT"))
            Loop Until (fileType = "TXT" Or fileType = "RTF" Or fileType = "HTML" Or fileType = "PDF")
    End Select

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFolder = fs.GetFolder(locFolder)
    Set tFolder = fs.CreateFolder(locFolder & "Converted")
    Set tFolder = fs.GetFolder(locFolder & "Converted")

    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
        Dim d As Document
        Set d = Application.Documents.Open(oFile.Path)
        strDocName = ActiveDocument.Name
        intPos = InStrRev(strDocName, ".")
        strDocName = Left(strDocName, intPos - 1)
        ChangeFileOpenDirectory tFolder
        Select Case fileType
            Case Is = "TXT"
                strDocName = strDocName & ".txt"
                ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=strDocName, FileFormat:=wdFormatText
        Case Is = "RTF"
                strDocName = strDocName & ".rtf"
                ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=strDocName, FileFormat:=wdFormatRTF
        Case Is = "HTML"
                strDocName = strDocName & ".html"
                ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=strDocName, FileFormat:=wdFormatFilteredHTML
        Case Is = "PDF"
                strDocName = strDocName & ".pdf"
                ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=strDocName, ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF
        End Select
        d.Close
        ChangeFileOpenDirectory oFolder
    Next oFile
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```